# apiResourece does not return values on custom method

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am using laravel `apiResources` for an api call, the problem is that i created a custom method named `closePeriod`, that when i try to fetch a period it return always

```
No query results for model [App\Entities\Accounting\Period]
```

this is the method, i try to get the Period with `Period::findOrFail($id)`, i have checked and `$id` has a value, and it exists in the database

```
Route::get('periods/close/{id}', 'PeriodController@closePeriod');
public function closePeriod($id) {
        if($period = Period::findOrFail($id)) {
            //do something
            return response()->json([
                'error' =>  false,
                'data'  => $period
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'The period was not found, please reaload and try again'
        ]);
    }
```

I have noticed that the api methods does work fine, i get the periods in `index`, `show` and can `create` and `edit` a period so i think the problem is in the custom method? why?

Comment: Is that a controller method?  I don't see where you are using an Eloquent Resource in your code?

Comment: @DavidHeremans yes is a controller method, and i am not using and eloquent resource, just [controller resouces](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes)

Comment: So it's a resource controller you mean?  A resource controller does not support your method; how do you expect Laravel to know that it needs to call that method?

Comment: @DavidHeremans i have set the route to the controller method. the problem is in why can't i fetch `Period` data? if it exists in the database and id has a value

Comment: Are you sure you're IN this method?  How does your router definition look like?

Comment: @DavidHeremans i added it to the question and added the route, and yes i am sure, if i return the id, i get a response from the method.